# Shopify/liquid - adding classes and removing injected text

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm working on a Shopify (slate) theme with very limited experience. There's a few classes I need to add which I've managed on images but can't find a way to do this on an anchor included within `<h2 class="mosaic__title p-name">{{ item.title | link_to: item.url }}</h2>`.

Also I have some prices that has text like "On Sale from" injected before it. I don't know how this is added or how to remove it. Here's an example:

```
<del>{{ item.compare_at_price | money }}</del>
{% assign sale_price = item.price | money %}
{{ 'products.product.on_sale_from_html' | t: price: sale_price }}
```

I've tried removing the `.on_sale_from_html` and `t: price: sale_price` but that doesn't work/it breaks.

Can anyone advise on this? Thanks!

Full section of code for reference:

```
<div class="mosaic__caption">
  <h2 class="mosaic__title p-name">{{ item.title | link_to: item.url }}</h2>

  {% if item.object_type == 'product' %}
    <p class="mosaic__value">
      {% if item.compare_at_price > item.price %}
        {% if item.price_varies %}
          <del>{{ item.compare_at_price | money }}</del>
          {% assign sale_price = item.price | money %}
          {{ 'products.product.on_sale_from_html' | t: price: sale_price }}
        {% else %}
          {{ 'products.product.on_sale' | t }}
          <data itemprop="price" class="p-price">{{ item.price | money }}</data>
        {% endif %}
        <data class="visually-hidden p-price">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</data>
      {% else %}
        {% if item.price_varies %}
          {% assign price = item.price | money %}
          <data itemprop="price" class="p-price">{{ 'products.product.from_text_html' | t: price: price }}</data>
        {% else %}
          <data itemprop="price" class="p-price">{{ item.price | money }}</data>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
      {% unless item.available %}
      {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
      {% endunless %}
    </p>
  {% else %}
    <p>{{ item.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 50 }}</p>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with the `link_to` filter. This code: `<h2 class="mosaic__title p-name">{{ item.title | link_to: item.url }}</h2>`

The `link_to` takes a URL and just creates a html link element with the provided text and link.

So the above code is the same as:

```
<h2 class="mosaic__title p-name">
  <a href="{{item.url}}">{{item.title}}</a>
</h2>
```

So you can write as an alternative the above code or use replace filter to add a class attribute like so for example: `item.title | link_to: item.url | replace: '<a', '<a class="foo"'`

---

As for your second question such outputs `{{ 'products.product.on_sale_from_html' | t: price: sale_price }}` points that this is a translatable text.

This means that your text is located in your translation file ( usually `en.default.json` in your `locales` folder ) so you can modify the text from there.

As for the text that is added, it seems that your translated string contains the following `{{ price }}` variable which is replaced via the passed variable `price: sale_price`.

PS: Read up the documentation in Shopify where these functions are described in more detail:
https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/url-filters#link_to
https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/internationalizing/locale-files#values

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat and I understand a bit more about the translation file. If I don't want the text at all can I just remove it from (for example) the `{{ 'products.product.on_sale_from_html' | t: price: sale_price }} ` code or should I just remove the text from the translation file, so just leave it blank?

Comment: It's up to you, if you don't want the string you remove the text. ( you can edit the language file from the admin panel as well, under `Themes -> More Actions -> Languages` ).

Comment: Yeah I don't need the text at all. I thought I'd just be able to remove the `t` reference and `on_sale_form_html` and it would just render the price but looks like I can't do that.